# R: Updating NAs in a data table with values of another data table

Tags: r, merge, data.table, na

There are two data tables of the following structure:

```
 DT1 <- data.table(ID=c("A","B","C"), P0=c(1,10,100), key="ID")
 DT2 <- data.table(ID=c("B","B","B","A","A","A","C","C","C"), t=rep(seq(0:2),3), P=c(NA,30,50,NA,4,6,NA,200,700))
```

In data table`DT2`all NAs in column `P` shall be updated by values `P0` out of data table `DT1`.

If `DT2` is ordered by `ID` like `DT1`, the problem can be solved like this:

```
 setorder(DT2,ID)
 idxr <- which(DT2[["t"]]==1)
 set(DT2, i=idxr, j="P", value=DT1[["P0"]])
```

But how can the data tables be "merged" without ordering `DT2` before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can join the two datasets `on` 'ID', for NA values in 'P', we assign 'P' as 'P0', and then remove the 'P0' by assigning it to 'NULL'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
DT2[DT1, on='ID'][is.na(P), P:= P0][, P0:= NULL][]
```

Or as @DavidArenburg mentioned, we can use `ifelse` condition after joining on 'ID' to replace the NA elements in 'P'.

```
DT2[DT1, P := ifelse(is.na(P), i.P0, P), on = 'ID']
```

Comment: I understand, what is done in each `[]`. Is this a kind of one after another operation?

Comment: @kamath It is similar to `%>%` in `dplyr`.  We are updating on the resulting dataset from each operation.

Comment: You could do this in one tep using `ifelse` as in `DT2[DT1, P := ifelse(is.na(P), i.P0, P), on = 'ID']`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, thanks, but I am not sure `ifelse` and data.table can be mixed up.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I updated.  I was thinking the `ifelse` would be slow compared to assigning.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Very nice solution. How i.P0 works? Where is some info about this syntax?

Comment: @mjaniec You will usually use `i.` prefix when you have column with the same name in two data sets that you are joining. Or if you want to be explicit in order to make your code bullet proof. `i.` just tells data.table to take the column from the data set in the `i`th location (as in `DT[i, j, by]`), so if you do a join of type `DT[DT2]`, then `DT2` will be in the `i`th location of `DT`, and if you want to be explicit about taking columns from `DT2`, you will prefix their names with `i.`. In the newer versions there also `x.` prefix. I think you can check out data.tables "NEWS" section on GH.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks a lot for swift and detailed answer! So i. refers to DT[i, ...]. I understand, using it is useful to bullet proof the code. In this simple case ifelse(is.na(P), P0, P) seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option of joining by condition

```
DT2[is.na(P), P := DT1[.SD, P0]]
DT2
#    ID t   P
# 1:  B 1  10
# 2:  B 2  30
# 3:  B 3  50
# 4:  A 1   1
# 5:  A 2   4
# 6:  A 3   6
# 7:  C 1 100
# 8:  C 2 200
# 9:  C 3 700
```