# Which data.table syntax for left join (one column) to prefer

Tags: r, data.table

How should I start thinking about which syntax I prefer?

My criteria is efficiency (this is number one) and also readability/maintainability.

This

```
A <- B[A, on = .(id)] # very concise!
```

Or that

```
A[B, on = .(id), comment := i.comment]
```

Or even (as PoGibas suggests):

```
A <- merge(A, B, all.x = TRUE)
```

For completeness then a more basic way is to use `match()`:

```
A[, comment := B[chmatch(A[["id"]], id), comment]]
```

Example data:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = rnorm(10)^2)
B <- data.table(id = c("c", "d", "e"), comment = c("big", "slow", "nice"))
```

Comment: If you want to assign the column in place, use the second method

Comment: Can't you just use `merge`: `merge(A, B, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: so the first method doesn't assign by reference?

Comment: You are assigning the output to the identifier 'A and the memory location should be different

Comment: We don't know what criteria you would use to prefer one over another. You can read the package vignettes if you want to hear the case for assign/update-by-reference. That's the only join that ever shows up in my workflow, usually like `A[, comment := B[.SD, on=.(id), x.comment]]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I didn't know you could use `.SD` like that! just edited with some words on my criteria

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I prefer the "update join" idiom for efficiency and maintainability:**

```
DT[WHERE, v := FROM[.SD, on=, x.v]]
```

It's an extension of what is shown in `vignette("datatable-reference-semantics")` under "Update some rows of columns by reference - *sub-assign* by reference". Once there is a vignette available on joins, that should also be a good reference.

This is efficient since it only uses the rows selected by `WHERE` and modifies or adds the column in-place, instead of making a new table like the more concise left join `FROM[DT, on=]`.

It makes my code more readable since I can easily see that the point of the join is to add column `v`; and I don't have to think through "left"/"right" jargon from SQL or whether the number of rows is preserved after the join.

It is useful for code maintenance since if I later want to find out how `DT` got a column named `v`, I can search my code for `v :=`, while `FROM[DT, on=]` obscures which new columns are being added. Also, it allows the `WHERE` condition, while the left join does not. This may be useful, for example, if [using `FROM` to "fill" NAs in an existing column `v`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33981955/1191259).

---

Compared with the other update join approach `DT[FROM, on=, v := i.v]`, I can think of two advantages. First is the option of using the `WHERE` clause, and second is transparency through warnings when there are problems with the join, like duplicate matches in `FROM` conditional on the `on=` rules. Here's an illustration extending the OP's example:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = rnorm(10)^2)
B2 <- data.table(
  id = c("c", "d", "e", "e"), 
  ord = 1:4, 
  comment = c("big", "slow", "nice", "nooice")
)

# left-joiny update
A[B2, on=.(id), comment := i.comment, verbose=TRUE]
# Calculated ad hoc index in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: comment,i.comment 
# Assigning to 4 row subset of 10 rows

# my preferred update
A[, comment2 := B2[A, on=.(id), x.comment]]
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(A, , `:=`(comment2, B2[A, on = .(id), x.comment])) :
#   Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'comment2' (1 unused)

    id     amount comment comment2
 1:  a 0.20000990    <NA>     <NA>
 2:  b 1.42146573    <NA>     <NA>
 3:  c 0.73047544     big      big
 4:  d 0.04128676    slow     slow
 5:  e 0.82195377  nooice     nice
 6:  f 0.39013550    <NA>   nooice
 7:  g 0.27019768    <NA>     <NA>
 8:  h 0.36017876    <NA>     <NA>
 9:  i 1.81865721    <NA>     <NA>
10:  j 4.86711754    <NA>     <NA>
```

In the left-join-flavored update, you silently get the final value of `comment` even though there are two matches for `id == "e"`; while in the other update, you get a helpful warning message (upgraded to [an error in a future release](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3310)). Even turning on `verbose=TRUE` with the left-joiny approach is not informative -- it says there are four rows being updated but doesn't say that one row is being updated twice.

---

I find that this approach works best when my data is arranged into a set of tidy/relational tables. A good reference on that is [Hadley Wickham's paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10).

** In this idiom, the `on=` part should be filled in with the join column names and rules, like `on=.(id)` or `on=.(from_date >= dt_date)`. Further join rules can be passed with `roll=`, `mult=` and `nomatch=`. See `?data.table` for details. Thanks to @RYoda for noting this point in the comments.

Here is a more complicated example from Matt Dowle explaining `roll=`: [Find time to nearest occurrence of particular value for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379658/find-time-to-nearest-occurrence-of-particular-value-for-each-row)

Another related example: [Left join using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598139/left-join-using-data-table/34600831#34600831)

Comment: Just an addendum: The `on=` part must be filled with the join column names (eg. `on=.(id)`. PS: Excellent answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Two comments/questions:
(1) I do see the beauty of your method but does it improve over the second original option (`v := i.v`)?
(2) The SQL jargon, isn't that bigger than just SQL [...wiki/Relational_algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)?
I would argue it is good to have some set of consistent vocabulary (jargon?) that one can use to communicate in places like this.

Comment: @snoram For (1), I edited to add a couple reasons. For (2), I guess it is partly an issue of preferences and background. With a normalized set of tables, I have never found a need for the various SQL joins (outer, inner, full, left, right, etc) or the lingo behind them... and sort of suspect that there's something inefficient in a workflow that requires them (outside of data cleaning). I have some familiarity with set theory and like the relational algebra terms, though (union, semi-, equi-, anti-joins, etc.)

Comment: @Frank I think your answer is a really good resource on joins with data.table. Recently updated to version 1.12.3 and now I get an error when I use `A[, comment2 := B2[A, on=.(id), x.comment]]` saying: _Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'comment2'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code._

Comment: @markus Thanks :) That error happens if B2 has duplicate rows for some ids. You can use `mult="first"` or `mult="last"` to select a value that way or otherwise calculate the selected value by some function like `A[, comment2 := B2[A, on=.(id), max(x.comment), by=.EACHI]$V1]`. Let me know if it doesn't make sense

Comment: I like this approach and I see the upsides. But one still has to `A[!is.na(comment2), comment := comment2]` to update the comment column compared to the classic update-join, no?

Comment: @alodi After seeing the `Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 10 items` warning (maybe now an error?), I would take a look at `B` again and see that it cannot be used to map from id -> comment and then decide how to fix things from there (eg, maybe drop dupes in B and try again).

Comment: For all the great advice given in this answer, this answer is also misleading to new data.table users. OP asks for advice on left join but this answer does *not* result in a typical left join. When there are multiple matches in B, it will not return all matches. You address this indirectly in your second example and by referring to this operation as "left-joiny" instead of "left-join". I would really recommend explicitly saying this is not performing as SQL-style left join, though.