# overwrite information in data.table in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

i have a data.table :

```
  data.table(id = c(rep(1,5)),
               year = c(rep(2015,3), rep(2016,2)), 
               class = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)),
               origin = c("Europe", "Asia", "Africa", "Europe", "Asia"), 
               count = c(30299, 3, 34, 2, 800))

   id year class origin count
1:  1 2015     A Europe 30299
2:  1 2015     A   Asia     3
3:  1 2015     A Africa    34
4:  1 2016     B Europe     2
5:  1 2016     B   Asia   800
```

but some of the information is not correct. I want to overwrite the region using another data.table:

```
  data.table(id = c(1),
             year = c(2015,2016), 
             class = c("A", "B"),
             origin = c("Europe", "Asia"))

   id year class origin
1:  1 2015     A Europe
2:  1 2016     B   Asia
```

so that the original table becomes :

```
  id year class origin count
1:  1 2015     A Europe 30299
2:  1 2015     A Europe     3
3:  1 2015     A Europe    34
4:  1 2016     B   Asia     2
5:  1 2016     B   Asia   800
```

i ried doing this with `merge` and also `within`, but i am getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named your first data.table `dt_A`, the second one `dt_B` and assume, you identify the entries in `dt_B` by `id`, `year` and `class`.

```r
dt_A[dt_B, on = c("id", "year", "class"), origin := i.origin]
```

returns

```r
   id year class origin count
1:  1 2015     A Europe 30299
2:  1 2015     A Europe     3
3:  1 2015     A Europe    34
4:  1 2016     B   Asia     2
5:  1 2016     B   Asia   800
```

Basically we did a left join to get the needed data and updated the `origin` column.

Comment: or `dt_A[, origin := dt_B[.SD, on = c("id", "year", "class"), origin]]` as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313203/4552295